# Timer firing on the wrong interval

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to abstract system.threading.timer based off this article:
http://www.derickbailey.com/CommentView,guid,783f22ad-287b-4017-904c-fdae46719a53.aspx

However, it seems the timer is firing according to the wrong parameter

In the class below we have this line

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(o => TimerExecute(), null, 1000, 30000);
```

This should mean wait for 1 second before starting, then fire every 30 seconds

However, the code is firing every one second

what have I done wrong

```
 public interface ITimer
    {
        void Start(Action action);
        void Stop();
    }

    public class Timer : ITimer, IDisposable
    {
        private TimeSpan timerInterval;
        private System.Threading.Timer timer;
        private Action timerAction;

        private bool IsRunning { get; set; }

        public Timer(TimeSpan timerInterval)
        {
            this.timerInterval = timerInterval;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            StopTimer();
        }

        public void Start(Action action)
        {
            timerAction = action;
            IsRunning = true;
            StartTimer();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsRunning = false;
            StopTimer();
        }

        private void StartTimer()
        {
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(o => TimerExecute(), null, 1000, Convert.ToInt32(timerInterval.TotalMilliseconds));
        }

        private void StopTimer()
        {
            if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                timer.Dispose();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        private void TimerExecute()
        {
            try
            {
                StopTimer();
                timerAction();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (IsRunning)
                    StartTimer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're passing timerInterval to the Timer class and using that later on to set the repeat interval. What is the value of timerInterval?

Comment: I changed the code to a hard coded value for the purposes of pasting it here. Guess that just caused confusion though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You restart the timer for every time it hits TimerExecute. And since it restart well it will trigger after 1 second again. So I would rewrite the TimerExecute to this.

Also your try catch or try finally methods, make sure you actually catch the problems and handle them in some way, not just ignore it.

```
private void TimerExecute()
    {
        try
        {
            timerAction();
        }
        catch
        {
            //todo
        }
    }
```